# How to achieve this in polymer

Tags: polymer

Is their any design templates(like WordPress or bootstrap) in polymer that having the effect of scrolling to next div or previous div onscroll and animating the previous div(like parallax-container) I tried parallax-container but it is having overflow I have used overflow: hidden; but display was not correct.Then I have implemented this functions and called when clicking key down and up arrows.

```
 scroll_down() {
    //dist = next element offsetTop
smooth_scroll_to(el,dist, 2000);
   //sliding previous div by adding animation name
 }
  scroll_up(){
  //dist = previous element offsetTop
smooth_scroll_to(el,dist, 2000);
//sliding  div by adding animation name
  }
```

When user clicks the same button multiple times or combination of both the buttons they are messing up (animation and scrolling) so I am searching for any template or any component. My divs are present inside the paper-header-panel

Any help is appreciated,

Thank you,

Babji.

Comment: This might help. https://customelements.io/search/parallax

Comment: I tried parallax-container but its scrolling horizontally. I tried making             overflow: hidden; but its showing the elements that having z-index value low as zoomed.

Comment: @Babji: the [demo](http://winhowes.github.io/parallax-container/components/parallax-container/demo/) is clearly scolling vertically. Please see the source code of the demo to find your issue.

Comment: @jdepypere: In that demo if u press mouse wheel button and move horizontally u will find horizontal scrolling, That y i am not using this( parallax-container)

Answer (score 1):

I've updated the parallax-container element in question with a patch to resolve this issue until the underlying issue with webkit is resolved. The latest version of the parallax-container element is 1.0.1 - let me know if there's any issues :)